# What is wrong with the following Code in C language?

Tags: c, pointers

I observed that in line `int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));` this code is trying to convert a void* into a int* without using proper typecasting. So according to me answer should be *option A*. But in official GATE-2017 exam answer key, *answer is given D.* So am i wrong ? how ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *assignval(int *x, int val){
  *x = val;
  return x;
}

void main(){
    clrscr();
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(NULL==x) return;
    x = assignval(x,0);
    if(x){
        x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        if(NULL==x) return;
        x = assignval(x,10);
    }
    printf("%d\n",*x);
    free(x);
    getch();
}
```

- (A) compiler error as the return of malloc is not typecast
  appropriately.
- (B) compiler error because the comparison should be made as x==NULL
  and not as shown.
- (C) compiles successfully but execution may result in dangling
  pointer.
- (D) compiles successfully but execution may result in memory leak.

> In my opinion *option D* is only correct when `int *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` is used.

Comment: (1) Research about proper indentation. It's all the same for the compiler, but makes a great deal of difference to humans. (2) Why are you leaking the memory `x` points to by reallocating it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc. to eliminate A. The answer is D, since you overwrite the pointer `x`.

Comment: I also don't like `void main()`. A smart Alec would amend the exam question with this as option E.

Comment: [Don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#605858).

Comment: Your instructor either doesn't know C well, or this is a trick question. The `iostream.h` strongly implies a C++ compiler (an ancient compiler, in fact). which means option A is the only one that can possibly be correct.

Comment: @StoryTeller Is the very smart answer !

Comment: In C language you are *supposed* to convert `void *` to `int *` *without* explicit cast. That the right way to do it. Unnecessary explict casts are extremely bad practice and shoud be avoided at all costs wherever possible.

Comment: ok i got it. I should not be using iostream and conio. And that casting with malloc is not necessary in C but in C++ its necessary. Also im compiling my code with c++ compiler instead of c compiler. Thank you all

Comment: @Prakhar: If you are compiling your code as C++, then why are you misleading people by tagging your question as [C]?

Comment: @AnT i didnt know it untill now. Thats the reason i asked for help here and got answer. Sorry for discomfort anyway. Im new to C and C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no right answer among the choices offered.

The immediately obvious problems with the code, under assumption that the code is supposed to be written in standard C:

- Standard library does not have `<conio.h>` header or `<iostream.h>` header.
- `void main()` is illegal. Should be `int main()`. Even better `int main(void)`
- `clrscr()`, `getch()` - standard library knows no such functions.
- The second `malloc` leaks memory allocated by the first one (assuming the first one succeeds).
- Result of second `malloc` is explicitly cast - bad and unnecessary practice.

Comment: neglect conio.h, actually i was using an old ide (turbo c)

Comment: I got it answer is D which is right. Also standard library doesn't have iostream and conio header files. Memory leak will occur as we lose track of first assignment of memory to x. In C their is no need to manualy typecast malloc.

Comment: The `#include <iostream.h>` is a hint the code is (pre-standard) C++, not C.     That and the various points you raise suggest the quality of the exam itself is VERY low.

Answer (score 0):

The statement :

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

will not lead to compile error, as it declares `x` as a pointer to `int` and initializes it right afterwards. It did not have type `void` beforehand.

The statement :

```
x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

causes a possible memory leak, as it reallocates the memory which is already allocated for `x`.

---

***NOTE :*** However none of this answers is completely correct. This code will not compile for various reasons.

If this is your code, change :

```
void main()
```

to :

```
int main(void)
```

and also see [why you should not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Apart from that, `clrscr()`, `getch()`, `<conio.h>` and `<iostream.h>` are not recognized by standard library.

Comment: thanks. I get it their are lot of errors in this code.

Answer (score -1):

> *I observed that in line int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)); this code is trying to convert a void* into a int* without using proper typecasting.*

[There's more than a little debate about whether or not to cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), but it's a stylistic thing. `void *` is safely promoted to any other pointer.

ISO C 6.3.2.3 says...

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Whatever you choose, pick one and stick with it.

---

The memory leak is here:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(NULL==x) return;
x = assignval(x,0);
if(x){
    // Memory leak
    x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The first `malloc` points `x` at allocated memory. The second `malloc` can only happen if the first succeeded (if `x` is true). The pointer to the memory allocated by the first `malloc` is lost.

Using a new variable would fix the leak, keeping in mind that the code is nonsense.

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(NULL==x) return;
x = assignval(x,0);
if(x){
    int *y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(NULL==y) return;
    y = assignval(y,10);
    free(y);
}
```

---

As a side note, `void main()` is ***technically*** not a violation of the ISO C standard, it is "some other implementation-defined manner".

5.1.2.2.1 says:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
>
> or equivalent;) ***or in some other implementation-defined manner***.

I'm guessing you're using a Windows compiler, that would be the "some other implementation". `clang` considers it an error.

```
test.c:8:1: error: 'main' must return 'int'
void main(){
^~~~
int
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The `iostream.h` could hint that OP is using a *C++* compiler.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: The C++ header with similar name is called `<iosteam>`, not `<iostream.h>`.

Answer (score -1):

you should never forget that a void * pointer can be assigned to all type of pointers. in IDEs like visual studio, you get a compile error if you do not perform casting while assigning a void * to <>. for example:

```
float *ptr = malloc(sizeof(float));//compile error in visual studio.
```

but if you compile it with GCC without typecasting, you won't get a compile error.

Comment: That's because the compiler with Visual Studio is a C++ compiler, in which implicit conversion from `void *` to another pointer is not permitted.  In standard C, typecasting the return value from `malloc()` is permitted but is poor practice.

Comment: @Peter: Wrong. Compiler in Visual Studio is not a "C++ compiler". It is "whatever you configure it to be" compiler, which can properly compile C code and C++ code, exactly like GCC and most C/C++ compilers available today. Meanwhile, the above claim that the need to cast is somehow tied to "IDE" is completely nonsensical.